# Can Dspace7 import data from external API source?

Tags: dspace

I am new in Dspace.
I have successfull installed Dspace. but I want to import item from external source to Dspace using API (exampe : import from e-Library university website API to Dspace). It that possibe ? if this possible, how to consume/import it ?

I success installed Dspace, and read the documentation but can't find my issue